# Как добавить библиотеку в geany?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, geany

Как добавить библиотеку pi4j к geany на rasbian? Саму библиотеку скачал и установил (через консоль), но те примеры что в ней  есть не компилируются. 
Выдает такого рода ошибки

```
WiringPiSPIExample.java:30: error: package com.pi4j.wiringpi does not exist
```

может добавить classpath? если да то как это сделать?

Comment: Cогласно информации на официальном сайте https://pi4j.com/1.2/install.html:
компиляция: javac -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ...
запуск: java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ...

Comment: да, только такой папки как /opt... нет. Эту информацию я читал. Только не совсем понял что под " .:classes:" подразумевается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Вопрос не актуален. Нужно скрипт запускать. К тому же библиотеку устаревшая и не поддерживается